# Integrals of continuous functions (as an approximation of step functions)

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I need to..

Show that a continuous function $f \colon [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ with the properties $\forall x \in [a,b] f(x) \ge 0$ and $\int_a^b f = 0$, must be identically 0.

Now i can see why this is true. Its continuous hence 'smooth' between any two distinct points, meaning the integral would not be equal to 0 unless the function is 0 itself, right? But im not quite sure how to translate this.

Comment: Are you saying that you understand the statement intuitively, but can't prove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that $f(x_1)>0$ for some $x_1\in(a,b)$, let $\varepsilon=\frac12f(x_1)$ for that $x$.

As $f$ is continuous, it means that there is a $\delta\in\mathbb R_{>0}$ such as $|f(x)-f(x_1)|<\varepsilon$ (hence $f(x)>\varepsilon$) for any $x\in(x_1-\delta,x_1+\delta)$.

So now $$\int_{x_1-\delta}^{x_1+\delta}f(x) dx>\int_{x_1-\delta}^{x_1+\delta}\varepsilon dx=2\delta\varepsilon>0$$

And
\begin{align}
\int_a^bf(x)dx=&\int_a^{x_1-\delta}f(x)dx+\int_{x_1-\delta}^{x_1+\delta}f(x) dx>\int_{x_1+\delta}^bf(x) dx\\
&>0+2\delta\varepsilon+0>0.
\end{align}

Note: if $x_0=a$ or $x_0=b$ and with $f$ continuous, you can find another $x_1$ not equal to either $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Im not quite sure i understand the last line of the proof?

Comment: Also why do you conclude that $\int_a^b f(x) dx > 0 $ when i have to show its equal to 0?

Comment: Okay, @user65972, if $f$ is non-negative then its integral is non-negative.  Now, if there is a possitive value $f(x_1)$ and $f$ is continuous, then there is a neighborhood $\mathcal D$ in which $\int_{\mathcal D}f$ is absolutely possitive.  Before and after that neighborhood the integral is still non-negative $\int_{[a,b]\setminus\mathcal D}f\ge0$, the whole integration will be absolutely possitive which contradicts the initial hypothesis.

Comment: edit: i understand now. Its because we assume $f(x_0) >0 \Rightarrow  \int_a^b f(x) dx >0 $ so f must be 0?

Comment: Right!  I probably should have been more clear that this is a proof by contradiction.  Assuming that the conclusion is not true then show that an initial hypothesis should not be true.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $f(x_0)>0$ for some $x_0$ in [a,b] . Then, by continuity of f, there is some

Real $e>0 $ so that $f>0$ in $(x_0-e,x_0+e)$ . Then $\int_a^bfdx \geq $ $\int_ {x_0-e}^{x_0+e}fdx>0$